# Hide navigation bar and toolbar when user taps full screen image?

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I need help with setting up this functionality. From the first view controller the user taps a thumbnail image to go to this view controller that displays the image full screen. I have customized the look of the navigation bar so that it looks different from the rest of the app, so the same navigation bar is not linked from the previous.

I have managed to display the navigation bar how I want it and all the buttons work how I want them to, also. Now I just want to hide the navigation bar when the view appears and when the user taps, to show the nav bar, possibly even change the background color from black to white in that process. Here is what I have:

```
var profileImage: UIImage!
var tap = UITapGestureRecognizer()

@IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet var fullSizeImage: UIImageView!

override fun viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    self.fullSizeImage.image = profileImage
    self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
    self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 6.0

    tap.addTarget(self, action: "tappedScreen")
    fullSizeImage.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    fullSizeImage.userInteractionEnabled = true

    let navBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.frame.size.width, 44))
        navBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        navBar.delegate = self

        let navItem = UINavigationItem()
        navItem.title = "Profile Image"


        let leftButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "cancelButton:")
        leftButton.tintColor = UIColor(red: 37/255, green: 94/255, blue: 67/255, alpha: 1.0)

        let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Gallery", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "galleryButton:")
        rightButton.tintColor = UIColor(red: 37/255, green: 94/255, blue: 67/255, alpha: 1.0)

        navItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton
        navItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton

        navBar.items = [navItem]

        self.view.addSubview(navBar)

}

fun tappedScreen() {

    print("Tapped Screen")
}
```

Up to this point my debugger prints "Tapped Screen" when I tap, so I'm just looking for some code that will hide my navigation bar. I've tried many different ways and I know its going to be either:

```
navigationController?.barHideOnTapGestureRecognizer
// OR
navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true
// OR
navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
```

But I can't seem to put them in the right place or something, perhaps because of my custom navigation bar or because I have a custom segue from the previous view controller? I am using all the latest versions of swift, xCode, etc. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For me setting `navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true` in `viewDidLoad` works. Every time I click anywhere in the screen it hides the bars and then shows them respectively.

If you want to hide them and not show them again you can put `navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true` in your `tappedScreen` function.

If you want other scenarios please let me know!

Edit:
I got it!! :)

Ok u want to hide your navBar and not the navigationController!! so u can use this:

```
func tappedScreen()
{
    navBar!.hidden = true;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Unfortunately that's still not doing the trick.. I put navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true in viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear and tappedScreen and neither are doing it.. Any other suggestions?

Comment: This does work! But.. This only works when I set it in viewWillAppear and the function tappedScreen() cannot change the value of hidden. We're close! Also I need to set the same functionality for my bottom tool bar eventually.

Comment: So I've put together a little algorithm for different scenarios when i want the navBar hidden or showing. I can tap through and watch each scenario work but the only thing that doesn't work now is that navBar.hidden only works once, it cannot keep toggling.. I need a work-around for that.

Comment: but i did test and it works in tappedScreen function! please put your code to find out more. for example which statement is used to unhide the navBar?